# Return Zip File from ZipOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, zip, zipoutputstream

I have a function which creates a Zip file from a list of files. Is it possible to return the Zip file without it being saved on the disk? I need the file as I have to use the zip file as a parameter for another function. I am not sure of the ByteStream would be an option for me.

```
public File compressFileList(List<File> fileList,String fileName) {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream=null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
    String compressedFileName=fileName +".zip";
    if(fileList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    try
    {
        fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(compressedFileName);
        zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream));
        for (File file: fileList) {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ZipEntry zipEntry =  new ZipEntry(file.getName());
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
            int size = 0;
            while((size = fileInputStream.read(tmp)) != -1){
                zipOutputStream.write(tmp, 0, size);
            }
            zipOutputStream.flush();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
        zipOutputStream.close();
        return compressedFile; //This is what I am missing

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT : adding the use case**

The idea is to create a zip file and use the CreateClassifierOptions method of VisualRecognition Service of Watson.

```
classifierOptions = new CreateClassifierOptions.Builder()
            .classifierName("Santa")
            .addClass("Santa", new File("C:\\app\\GitRepo\\images\\beagle.zip"))
            .negativeExamples(new File("C:\\app\\GitRepo\\images\\nosport.zip"))
            .build();
```

The builder accepts the zip file as the parameter.

**Understanding**

Based on the explanation from Alexandre Dupriez, I think it is better to store the file at some place on the hard disk.

Comment: what does the other function accept as an Input? An `Inputstream`?

Comment: I am using WatsonService API, which accepts a zip file as input. or maybe i should create a temp zip file and return it to the function

Comment: Your question conflicts with your method signature. A File object is basically a reference to a file stored in some path, but your question seems to be about returning the (byte) contents of a file. So if you don't want to store your file somewhere, then you shouldn't be returning a File object.

Comment: Should I create a temporary file on the disk and send it to function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from a functional perspective? Storing a temporary file and returning a reference to it is an option, but it depends on what you want to do with that file.

Comment: I want to use the Watson Visual API. The  Visual API uses a zip file as argument. I have decided to store the file in a temporary folder and use it to call the Visual API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`:

```
zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
```

The difficulty here is to provide a `File` to the method consuming the zip file. The `java.io.File` does not provide an abstraction which allows you to manipulate in-memory files.

**The `java.io.File` abstraction and `java.io.FileInputStream` implementation**

To simplify, if we had to boil down what the `File` abstraction is, we would see it as a `URI`. And therefore, to be able to build an in-memory `File`, or at least mimic it, we would need to provide an `URI` which would then be used by the consumer of the `File` to read its content.

If we look at the `FileInputStream` which the consumer is likely to use, we can see that it always ends up with a native call which gives us to possibility whatsoever to abstract a `FileSystem` for in-memory files:

```
// class java.io.FileInputStream
/**
 * Opens the specified file for reading.
 * @param name the name of the file
 */
private native void open0(String name) throws FileNotFoundException;
```

It would be easier if there was a possibility to adapt the consumer to accept an `InputStream`, but from your problem statement I guess this is not possible.

**API call**

Your requirement is to provide a `File` to the Watson Visual API.
Could you please provide the API method you need to call?

Comment: I have mentioned that I want the above function to return a File. The calling function accepts only a Zip file as input.

Comment: Yes, please - wonder what could be done and if there is a workaround

Comment: I have added the use case. I assume that it is better to save the file and then call the watson service.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void compressFileList(List<File> fileList, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream =
            new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream));
        for (File file: fileList) {
            try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
                int size = 0;
                while((size = fileInputStream.read(tmp)) != -1){
                    zipOutputStream.write(tmp, 0, size);
                }
                zipOutputStream.flush();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // Maybe skip not found files.
                Logger.log(Level.INFO, "File not found {}", file.getPath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (fileList.isEmpty()) {
    ...
    return;
}
try {
    compressFileList(fileList, servletRequest.getOutputStream())) {
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesnt return a file. I am looking for an option to return a zip file. I have reallized that i will have to save the file temporarily before I could use it for the next function.

Comment: Or (as int my answer) you can pass an OutputStream for delivery of the zip file. Then you do not need to maintain a byte array with the zip files content.